Generating highly non-independent random samples
I'm testing performance of statistical tests in the face of non-independent data and I'd like to generate random data where I know the underlying statistical distribution.
The easiest way to do it is to generate correlated data, e.g. like so:
a <- rnorm(10000)
b <- -a + rnorm(10000, 0, 0.00001)

In this example a and b have very strong negative correlation, but when tested using paired t-test, it will still show that the null hypothesis holds (the distribution of p-values is uniform when performing multiple tests).
The problem is that when I test such correlated data using regular t-test for independent samples, then at alpha=0.05 I'm getting only about 16.6% false positive rate.
Is there a away to generate more non-independent data for which the paired t-test (or non-parametric tests like the sign test or Wilcoxon signed-rank test) shows no excessive false positive rate but the unpaired one shows very significant rates of false positives?
Ideally I'd like to be able to generate data for which unpaired t-test or Kolmogorov-Smirnov test regularly provides p-values smaller than 1e-6 for samples of few thousand measurements but which when tested using pairwise tests still have uniform distribution of p-values.

No, you can't!
Let's look at an example from your code.
> t.test(a,b,paired=TRUE)

    Paired t-test

data:  a and b
t = 1.7971, df = 9999, p-value = 0.07235
alternative hypothesis: true mean difference is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.003274242  0.075419931
sample estimates:
mean difference 
     0.03607284 

> t.test(a,b,paired=FALSE)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  a and b
t = 2.5415, df = 19998, p-value = 0.01105
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.008251937 0.063893752
sample estimates:
  mean of x   mean of y 
 0.01803640 -0.01803644 

> 2.5415/1.7971
[1] 1.414223

So the $t$-statistic is inflated, but only by $\sqrt{2}$.
Let's look at some variances
> c(var(a), var(b), var(a)+var(b), var(a-b))
[1] 1.007312 1.007312 2.014623 4.029246

The unpaired t-test uses (roughly) $2/n$ as the variance of the difference in means and the paired test uses $4/n$, and they aren't that different. You can't make $\mathrm{var}[A-B]$ arbitrarily larger than $\mathrm{var}[A]+\mathrm{var}[B]$, only twice as large.  Since you want the $t$-statistic for the paired test to be well calibrated, you can't get arbitrarily bad calibration for the unpaired test.
In the other direction you can make things as extreme as you like with positive correlation, that is, you can make the power or size of the unpaired test arbitrarily low while preserving the operating characteristics of the paired test.

does this hold also for non-parametric tests, like the KS-test?

It's got to more or less hold for the rank tests, because they are just location tests on some transformed scale.  I don't know about the KS test -- I don't think I've ever seen someone do a paired KS test as a location test, though

So, I've marked it as accepted answer, but would you have references to any peer reviewed papers that show this in more formalized manner?

No, I don't know of any.
